# Change ggplot2 to plotly with checkboxInput

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly

I have this shiny app for K-Means Clustering:

[image]

```
ui <- navbarPage("My Application",
                 tabPanel("K-Means", icon = icon("folder-open"),
                          sidebarLayout(
                            sidebarPanel(
                              sliderInput("num_centers", 
                                          label = "Select K",
                                          min = 2,
                                          max = 10,
                                          value = 2),
                              checkboxInput("plotly_checkbox", label = "Interactivity with plotly", value = TRUE)
                              ),
                            mainPanel(
                              plotOutput("kmeans")
                            )
                          )
                 )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$kmeans <- renderPlot({

    # Require number of centers
    req(input$num_centers)

    # K-Means Algorithm
    k_centers <- reactive({kmeans(x = harvard_scaled, centers = input$num_centers)})
    harvard_cluster <- augment(k_centers(), harvard_processed)


    # Static Plot 
    harvard_cluster %>% 
      janitor::clean_names() %>% 
      ggplot(aes(nevents, nplay_video, color = cluster)) +
      geom_point() +
      labs(x = "# of interactions with the course",
           y = "# of play video events",
           color = "Cluster") +
      xlim(0, 52000) +
      ylim(0, 12500) +
      ggtitle(paste("K-Means Clustering of students where", "K =", input$num_centers))
  })
}



# Create Shiny app object
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

- As you can see, I'd like to enable user to choose and see a `plotly` graph by using `checkboxInput`.
- I've tried a `ifelse` to no avail because one is a static graph and needs `renderPlot` and the other is an interactive graph and needs `renderPlotly`.

Does anyone know how to enable the user to select whether app shows `plotly` or `ggplot` graph?

EDIT: Example Dataset (Note: This is a dummy dataset different from the one I used to plot the above):

```
structure(c(0.150884824647657, 0.150884824647657, 0.449543446630647, 
0.217253407310543, -0.230734525663942, -0.330287399658272, -0.960788934955696, 
0.715017777282194, 0.449543446630647, -0.147773797335334, -0.380063836655437, 
-0.612353875975541, -0.463024564984046, -0.811459623964201, -1.60788261591884, 
-1.60788261591884, -0.89442035229281, 2.04238943053993, 1.7105465172255, 
2.29127161552575, 0.233845552976265, -0.761683186967036, -0.811459623964201, 
-1.12671039161291, -0.147773797335334, 1.19619000158812, 0.980492107933741, 
1.7105465172255, -0.711906749969871, -0.0648130690067253, -0.844643915295645, 
0.217253407310543, -0.570619818667904, -0.570619818667904, -0.990182090888924, 
0.22009369436402, 1.04308122833602, -0.046166978391628, 1.04308122833602, 
-0.677930938293665, -0.725535119180281, -0.509299178881755, -0.509299178881755, 
0.363713087547369, 0.363713087547369, 0.363713087547369, 1.94675381465822, 
1.84993175183798, 1.68856164713759, -1.226589294275, -1.25079480998006, 
-1.28790993406115, -0.892553177545187, 0.704204008465197, 0.591244935174923, 
0.962396175985825, 1.36582143773681, -1.22416874270449, -0.890939476498183, 
-1.09426580842068, 0.970464681220845, -0.691647397193198, 0.567039419469864, 
-0.885291522833669), .Dim = c(32L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("Mazda RX4", 
"Mazda RX4 Wag", "Datsun 710", "Hornet 4 Drive", "Hornet Sportabout", 
"Valiant", "Duster 360", "Merc 240D", "Merc 230", "Merc 280", 
"Merc 280C", "Merc 450SE", "Merc 450SL", "Merc 450SLC", "Cadillac Fleetwood", 
"Lincoln Continental", "Chrysler Imperial", "Fiat 128", "Honda Civic", 
"Toyota Corolla", "Toyota Corona", "Dodge Challenger", "AMC Javelin", 
"Camaro Z28", "Pontiac Firebird", "Fiat X1-9", "Porsche 914-2", 
"Lotus Europa", "Ford Pantera L", "Ferrari Dino", "Maserati Bora", 
"Volvo 142E"), c("mpg", "disp")), "`scaled:center`" = c(mpg = 20.090625, 
disp = 230.721875), "`scaled:scale`" = c(mpg = 6.0269480520891, 
disp = 123.938693831382))
```

Comment: Can you provide some data so that this becomes a reproducible example? Otherwise, it's hard for others to know whether the code they suggest actually will work.

Comment: Okay sure thing @phalteman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple solution is to use a `conditionalPanel()`, if that works for you. Here's an example

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxInput("typeplotly", "Use interactivity", FALSE),
  conditionalPanel("input.typeplotly == true", plotlyOutput("plotly")),
  conditionalPanel("input.typeplotly == false", plotOutput("plot"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plotly <- renderPlotly({
    ggplotly(ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point())
  })
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```